# why is the remaining number of occupants not calculated correctly?

Tags: java, testing

I'm coding a rescue simulation program and while applying the required tests it keeps giving a failure saying that the number of occupants remaining in the building is not correctly calculated and I can't figure out why!
below i provided the two methods that are supposed to give back the number of occupants.
Thanks in advance!

```
public void treat(){
    boolean f=false;
    if(!f){
          ((Disaster)((Citizen)this.getTarget()).getDisaster()).setActive(false);
               ResidentialBuilding r= (ResidentialBuilding)this.getTarget();
              if(r.getOccupants().size()!=0){
                 for(int i=0;i<r.getOccupants().size();i++){
                     if(this.getPassengers().size()<=this.getMaxCapacity()){
                          f=true;
                          Citizen z=(Citizen)r.getOccupants().get(i);
                          if(z.getState()!=CitizenState.DECEASED){
                              r.getOccupants().remove(i);
                              this.getPassengers().add(z);
                          }    
                      }

                  }
              } 
              else{
                  this.setState(UnitState.IDLE);
                  this.jobsDone();
              }
          }
        else
            this.cycleStep();

        }   




    public void cycleStep(){
        if(super.getDistanceToBase()==0)
            super.getWorldListener().assignAddress(this, 0, 0);
        if(super.getTarget()!=null){
            if(this.getLocation()== this.getTarget().getLocation()){
                this.setDistanceToBase(this.getLocation().getX() + this.getLocation().getY());
            }
            else if(this.getDistanceToBase()<=0){
                this.setDistanceToBase(0);
                this.setLocation(new Address(0,0));
                for (int i = 0; i < this.getPassengers().size(); i++) {
                    Citizen c = (Citizen)this.getPassengers().remove(i);

                }
            }
            else{
                this.setDistanceToBase(this.getDistanceToBase()-this.getStepsPerCycle());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're removing some of the elements of the list while looping through it.  What happens if you reverse the loop order?

Comment: `boolean f=false;
    if(!f)`: this already doesn't make sense. What's the point of an if block that is guaranteed to be executed, and of an else block that is guaranteed not to be?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<r.getOccupants().size();i++)` followed by `r.getOccupants().remove(i);`, you should either use i-- to repeat that slot, or go from the end to the front

Comment: @JBNizet Nizet yeah I just discovered this thanks!

Comment: @phflack I tried what you said and it didn't do any change actually it keeps saying that the number calculated is wrong

Comment: Does it still skip over people if you do that?  There may have been more issues than just that